# Calculate accuracy on both train and test

Tags: plot, caffe, training-data, pycaffe

I have 200 training data with 6000 features and labels are (0, +1) that have been converted to `HDF5` format. (Like that, i have 77 testing data).

I am working on plotting statistics like the accuracy over iterations. I use parse_log and gnuplot for that. Now my problem is that I need accuracy for both testset and trainset. In other words, I want that the TEST phase will be applied on both databases and as a result give me two accuracy numbers in order to see how the two courves evolve.
My `accuracy layer` in

> train_val.prototxt

is:

```
layer {
  name: "accuracy"
  type: "Accuracy"
  bottom: "sigm_l2"
  bottom: "label1"
  top: "accuracy" 
}
```

And My in solver.prototxt is:

```
    test_state: { stage: 'test-on-train' }
    test_iter: 500
    test_state: { stage: 'test-on-test' }
    test_iter: 100
    test_interval: 500
    test_compute_loss: true
    base_lr: 0.00001
    momentum: 0.9
    weight_decay: 0.000005
    # The learning rate policy
    lr_policy: "inv"
    gamma: 0.0001
    power: 0.75
    # Display every 100 iterations
    display: 100
    # The maximum number of iterations
    max_iter: 65000
    # snapshot intermediate results
    # solver mode: CPU or GPU
    solver_mode: CPU
```

And accuracy for both train and test is:

> (test_accuracy)

[image: test_acc]

> And train Accuracy is:

[image]

**I wonder why train accuracy is not change in iterations (in TRAIN phase)**.

Comment: @Shai, I have one output in previous inner product layer